# Cumulocity microservice deployment: access is denied

Tags: java, microservices, cumulocity

### My goal (background info)

I want to develop a java microservice on cumulocity. It should be able to do the following:
I would send "112233" to the microservice as follows:
https://myTenant.cumulocity.com/service/my-application-name/decode?data=112233
The microservice should then split the data into "11" for the first measurement and "22" for the second measurement etc. These measurements would be POSTed to cumulocity.

### My problem

I am now stuck on getting the [Hello, microservice tutorial](https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/java/java-microservice/) to work. I can't deploy the microservice (zip file) to cumulocity. 
`"error":"security/Forbidden","info":"https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/reference-guide/#error_reporting","message":"Access is denied"}` (I am an admin user.)

I also tried to upload the zip file via the website, this created a `HOSTED` application instead of a `MICROSERVICE`. Uploading my zip via a POST request to a `HOSTED` application actually works (which I obviously don't need).

I suspect that I get the "access denied" error cause cumulocity thinks that I upload a `HOSTED` application to a `MICROSERVICE`.

### What I've done so far

#### Code side

I downloaded the [hello-world-microservice example](https://bitbucket.org/m2m/cumulocity-examples/src/4a67ea4ab039/hello-world-microservice/?at=develop) from the cumulocity bitbucket development branch. (This code is not available on the default branch).
I changed the cumulocity versions to `9.3.0`, only this version seems to exist.

**The HelloWorldMain.java is unedited**

This is my **cumulocity.json** manifest file: (the roles make no difference)

```
{  
 "apiVersion":"1",
 "type":"MICROSERVICE",
 "version":"@project.version@",
 "availability":"PRIVATE",
 "provider":{  
     "name":"Cumulocity GmbH"
 },
 "isolation":"MULTI_TENANT",
 "requiredRoles":[  
     "ROLE_APPLICATION_MANAGEMENT_ADMIN",
     "ROLE_MEASUREMENT_ADMIN",
     "ROLE_INVENTORY_ADMIN"
 ],
 "roles":[  
     "ROLE_APPLICATION_MANAGEMENT_ADMIN",
     "ROLE_MEASUREMENT_ADMIN",
     "ROLE_INVENTORY_ADMIN"
 ],
 "livenessProbe":{  
     "httpGet":{  
         "path":"/health",
         "port":80
     },
     "initialDelaySeconds":15,
     "periodSeconds":10
 },
 "readinessProbe":{  
     "httpGet":{  
         "path":"/health",
         "port":80
     }
 }
}
```

This is my **application.properties** file

```
application.name=my-application-name
server.port=80
C8Y.baseURL=https://myTenant.cumulocity.com
C8Y.bootstrap.tenant=myTenant
C8Y.bootstrap.user=servicebootstrap_my-application-name
C8Y.bootstrap.password={SECRET_BOOTSTRAP_PASSW}
C8Y.user={MY_USERNAME}
C8Y.password={SECRET_PASSW}
C8Y.bootstrap.register=true
C8Y.microservice.isolation=MULTI_TENANT
C8Y.bootstrap.initialDelay=10000
```

#### Cumulocity side

I successfully **created** a microservice application,
GET https://myTenant.cumulocity.com/application/applications/5886 returns:

```
{  
 "availability":"PRIVATE",
 "id":"5886",
 "key":"my-application-key",
 "manifest":{  
     "imports":[  
     ],
     "noAppSwitcher":true
 },
 "name":"my-application-name",
 "owner":{  
     "self":"https://myTenant.cumulocity.com/tenant/tenants/myTenant",
     "tenant":{  
         "id":"myTenant"
     }
 },
 "requiredRoles":[  
     "ROLE_APPLICATION_MANAGEMENT_ADMIN",
     "ROLE_MEASUREMENT_ADMIN",
     "ROLE_INVENTORY_ADMIN"
 ],
 "roles":[  
     "ROLE_APPLICATION_MANAGEMENT_ADMIN",
     "ROLE_MEASUREMENT_ADMIN",
     "ROLE_INVENTORY_ADMIN"
 ],
 "self":"https://myTenant.cumulocity.com/application/applications/5886",
 "type":"MICROSERVICE"
}
```

I also successfully **subscribed** to this application.

When I try to upload the zip file to cumulocity, I get this error:
`"error":"security/Forbidden","info":"https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/reference-guide/#error_reporting","message":"Access is denied"}`
(Uploading to a `HOSTED` type application works fine, but I don't want that.)

> **note**: I also tried to use the [microservice deploy script](https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/reference/microservice-package/), this gave the same result as doing everything manually.

#### Trying to run it locally

Since I couldn't get it to work on the cumulocity platform, I tried to run it locally via docker. I ran it with this command:
`docker run -e "C8Y_MICROSERVICE_ISOLATION=MULTI_TENANT" 10aa0b73ddb3`

> **note**: I had to add the "C8Y_MICROSERVICE_ISOLATION=MULTI_TENANT" [environment variable](https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/reference/microservice-runtime/). if I didn't add this, I'd get credential/permission issues. This seems weird to me, since all other info is read from the **application.properties** file except for this one.

I have no errors when running this image on a local docker.

According to the [Hello, microservice tutorial](https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/java/java-microservice/), I should be able to request   `curl -H "Authorization: {AUTHORIZATION}" https://myTenant.cumulocity.com/service/my-application-name/hello?who=me`
This returns:
`{"error":"microservice/Not Found","info":"https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/reference-guide/#error_reporting","message":"Microservice my-application-name not found."}`

### Back to the questions

Has anyone else had difficulties with setting up a microservice on cumulocity?
Is there something I'm totally overseeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The microservice hosting needs to be assigned to your tenant otherwise it won't work and the API in that case will return forbidden. So it might be that it is no issue with your user but that your tenant has the feature not activated.

Comment: How would I be able to activate that "microservice hosting" feature? (I am the owner of the account, could it matter that it is a trial account?)

Comment: This can only be activated through the owner of the system. By default it is not assigned to tenants so trial accounts won't have it. So if you have a tenant on cumulocity.com this feature can only be enabled through someone at Cumulocity.